# Excel, power query merging two columns with a certain condition

Tags: excel, powerquery

```
Column1|Column2
----------------
blank  |name
blank  |name
number |description
number |description
number |description
blank  |name
blank  |name
```

This is a tiny structure of my excel power query data-set, so i want to merge these two columns, but only blank cells have to be filled with the second columns' datas, if the first columns have a data, the formula have to skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Column .. Custom Column ...

if [Column1] = null then [Column2] else  [Column1]

Then remove extra columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [Column1] = null then [Column2] else [Column1]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Column2"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```